# netcore DI container returns different instances for same registration with overloads

Tags: .net-core

I encountered a Problem with the DI framework of netcore. I am aware about the different ways to register an type in the DI container.

Specifically I am interested in the `.AddSingleton` method. There are many overlaods of this method.

My Problem is that I want to ensure that when I register the same class in different ways (with an interface and just with the class type), then two instances are created, one for each "registration" way.

Lets say I have an Interface called `ISomeInterface` an one implementation of it named `ImplementationOfSomeInterface`.

In my case I want the DI system to create an instance whenever the `ImplementationOfSomeInterface` is requested. Further I have some places where I define the dependency just with the interface `ISomeInterface`.

The Problem is that the DI system returns 2 instances of `ImplementationOfSomeInterface`. One for the case where the dependency is related of the class and one for the case where the dependency is given by the Interface.

I already checked many documentation and tutorials, but they all just explain the differences of `AddSingleton`, `AddScoped` etc...

```
// registration with the class type
services.AddSingleton<ImplementationOfSomeInterface>()

//registration with an interface and the corresponding 'same' class type
services.AddSingleton<ISomeInterface, ImplementationOfSomeInterface>();

//--------- now the usage of it -------------------
public TestClassA(SomeInterfaceImplementation instance)
    {
      var resultingInstA = instance;

    }

    public TestClassB(ISomeInterface instance)
    {
      var resultingInstB = instance;

    }

//I would expect that resultingInstA is pointing to the very same object of 
//resultingInstB => but they are different!
```

I would expect that `resultingInstA` is pointing to the very same object of `resultingInstB` => but they are different!

How can I achieve that I get the same instance back?

Comment: Unfortunately they will never be the same as you have described them to the DI as two different things. The DI can understand that 'SomeInterfaceImplementation' is of type 'ISomeInterface' (as you told it so) and that it should be a Singleton. It can not however know that 'ISomeInterface' and 'SomeInterfaceImplementation' should be the same singleton.
I would suggest to always inject the Interface and then you should not have this issue.

Comment: hi van. thank you as well, i tried to rewrite the methods in a way that all dependencies are resolved via interface, works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by registering an instance of the class rather than just the type.

```
var instance = new ImplementationOfSomeInterface();
services.AddSingleton(instance);
services.AddSingleton<ISomeInterface>(instance);
```

Now any attempt to resolve `ImplementationOfSomeInterface` or `ISomeInterface` will both return the instance initialized here.